# restTemplate.postForObject org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found

Tags: spring, rest

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody String provisionUser(@RequestBody(required = true)  String body) { 
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("key", "<key>");
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(body, headers);
    String APIendpoint = "https://apiendpont.com/provision";            
    String obj = restTemplate.postForObject(APIendpoint, request, String.class);
    return obj;
}
```

the restTemplate.postForObject() line in the above method is returning

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

I have tested the uri, and the header information in a REST client and receive a response - so I know that is the correct url.

I ran this in debug mode and the exception is thrown in RestTemplate.doExecute

```
protected <T> T doExecute(URI url, HttpMethod method, RequestCallback requestCallback,
        ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor) throws RestClientException {

    Assert.notNull(url, "'url' must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(method, "'method' must not be null");
    ClientHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        ClientHttpRequest request = createRequest(url, method);
        if (requestCallback != null) {
            requestCallback.doWithRequest(request);
        }
        response = request.execute();
        if (!getErrorHandler().hasError(response)) {
            logResponseStatus(method, url, response);
        }
        else {
            handleResponseError(method, url, response);
        }
        if (responseExtractor != null) {
            return responseExtractor.extractData(response);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ResourceAccessException("I/O error on " + method.name() +
                " request for \"" + url + "\":" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    finally {
        if (response != null) {
            response.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what's going on?  Thanks.